# git diff between working copy and branch base

Tags: git, git-diff

I can compare the tip of master and my working copy with

```
git diff master
```

I can compare the tip of the current branch with its merge base from master with

```
git diff master...
```

Is the a `git diff` command to compare the merge base of the current branch and the working copy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the are `git diff` command to compare the merge base of the current branch and the working copy?

If you current branch is not master, you can try in a bash shell:

```
git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master)
```

If uses [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) with `--fork-point`:

```
git merge-base --fork-point <ref> [<commit>]
```

> Find the point at which a branch (or any history that leads to `<commit>`) forked from another branch (or any reference) `<ref>`.
>   This does not just look for the common ancestor of the two commits, but also takes into account the reflog of `<ref>` to see if the history leading to `<commit>` forked from an earlier incarnation of the branch `<ref>`.