# How to transform a branch in only one commit in a new branch?

Tags: git

I have one Branch that I have a lot of changes and rebasing. 
Although, right now I wish to create a new branch with all my changes to this new Branch. 
For example, I have the Branch  `Developer` with 10 Commits, now I wish to create the `Developer v2` with all 10 commits in only one commit in this new branch, so I can take the Developer v2 and start to work on it and delete the `Developer`.

**EDIT**:
My question is a little bit different, I don't want to transform all my commits in only one and commit in master for example. If I wish I can do it:
`git checkout master 
git pull 
git checkout <branch_name>
git rebase -i master
Git checkout master
git merge <branch_name>`

What I want is create a new branch from master called v2 and them apply all my changes of the branch developer on V2, so I can delete the Developer Branch and they don't have any relation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about *commit squashing*.

Comment: Hmmm Quetin and Oliver, not like that. For squash in one commit I can do 
`git checkout master |
git pull |
git checkout <branch_name> |
git rebase -i master |
Git checkout master |
git merge <branch_name> `

What I really wish to start a new branch with only one commit, but with all my old changes from my old branch. 
So I create a new branch from Master for example and apply all my changes of the old branch in this Branch

Comment: Did you try first creating the new branch based on the Developer branch, then squashing the commits, which will only apply to the new branch?

Comment: No, I didn't ypnos. I will try it

Comment: That's still a squash-like operation, and in fact, you might want to use `git merge --squash` to achieve it (note that this kind of `git merge` does not make a merge!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I wish and it calls patch.

`git diff master Branch1 > ../patchfile
git checkout Branch2 
git apply ../patchfile`

Answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800902/git-generate-patch-for-all-commits-in-a-branch), so everything that I did on Branch1 can be applied to Branch2. It worked really good for me.