# "Export" a local branch in git for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

I'm sure it's a dumb question, but I've never used git before. I'm using the git extension for Visual Studio 2019, cloned a remote repository, created a new local branch and created/modified some files. I don't want to push my local changes to the remote server, but send my local changes to a research fellow. Is there a way to send him only the newly added/modified files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of connectivity which exists between your workstation and your research fellow, you could simply [bundle your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309).

Bundle only your branch (especially is the repo is huge)

```
git bundle create ../abundle yourBranch
```

Or even with less commits (very small bundle, assuming `yourBranch` comes from `master`)

```
git bundle create ../aBundle master..yourBranch
```

That will give you *one* file, which is easy to copy around/send to your colleague.
Said colleague will be able to fetch from it, getting your branch in the process.

The other approach is to [generate a patch from your branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802061/6309) (that would hide the history of all commits in that branch though)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Say my local branch is called "local-branch". Do I need to invoke the bundle command (in the local repository folder) as `git bundle create local-branch.bundle master`? How can I verify what the created bundle contains?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Unless your repository is huge, I would not bother and bundle everything: `git bundle create ../local-branch.bundle --all`. To check, you can simply clone that bundle elsewhere (`git clone local-branch.bundle`: you can clone from a  bundle *file*) and do a `git branch -avvv`: you will see your branch in there.

Comment: Unfortunately, the repository *is* huge.

Comment: @0xbadf00d OK: you can bundle your branch only. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `git bundle create ../abundle -- local-branch` yields the error "rev-list died".

Comment: @0xbadf00d What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Sorry, I realized I included '`--`' which are not needed here. I have edited the answer.